# Read multiple files, compare values and create a list of presence or absence of parameters

Tags: python, list

Please I need help with this.

I have 12 files I am trying to compare the presence or absence of a region that is defined in "key_file.txt" and produce a list that shows this.
I have written the following code but I get the following error.

> ```
> File "filter_bedtools_all_samples_new.py", line 119, in <module>
>     start = elems[1]
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Here is the code

```
 import sys

 #read each file from the argument list
 A1_file = sys.argv[1]
 A2_file = sys.argv[2]
 A3_file = sys.argv[3]

 B1_file = sys.argv[4]
 B2_file = sys.argv[5]
 B3_file = sys.argv[6]

 C1_file = sys.argv[7]
 C2_file = sys.argv[8]
 C3_file = sys.argv[9]

 D1_file = sys.argv[10]
 D2_file = sys.argv[11]
 D3_file = sys.argv[12]

 key_file = sys.argv[13]

 offset1 = int(sys.argv[14])
 offset2 = int(sys.argv[15])

 out_file = sys.argv[16]

 #open the output file
 outHandle = open(out_file,'w')

 #create a class to hold objects
 class Island:
    def __init__(self, chr, start, end):
            self.chr = chr
            self.start = start
            self.end = end

 #start reading files into lists
 with open(A1_file) as A1:
        list1 = A1.readlines()

 with open(A2_file) as A2:
        list2 = A2.readlines()

 with open(A3_file) as A3:
        list3 = A3.readlines()

 with open(B1_file) as B1:
        list4 = B1.readlines()

 with open(B2_file) as B2:
        list5 = B2.readlines()

 with open(B3_file) as B3:
        list6 = B3.readlines()

 with open(C1_file) as C1:
        list7 = C1.readlines()

 with open(C2_file) as C2:
        list8 = C2.readlines()

 with open(C3_file) as C3:
        list9 = C3.readlines()

 with open(D1_file) as D1:
        list10 = D1.readlines()

 with open(D2_file) as D2:
        list11 = D2.readlines()

 with open(D3_file) as D3:
        list12 = D3.readlines()

 #create a list containing the filenames

 file_list = ["list1","list2","list3","list4","list5","list6","list7","list8","list9","list10","list11","list12"]

 #print(len(list1))

 key_dict = {}
 out_dict = {}
 key_list = []
 counter = 0

 #open key file and read one line at a time
 with open(key_file) as kf:
     for eachline in kf:
    #initialize a dictionary of lists to 0
    temp_list = "list_" + str(counter)
    temp_list = [0] * 12
    out_dict[counter] = temp_list

    els = eachline.split("\t")
    k_chr = els[0]
    k_start = els[1]
    k_end = els[2]

    #create a dictionary of objects Island
    temp_obj = Island(k_chr,k_start,k_end)
    key_dict[counter] = temp_obj
    key_list.append(eachline) #decided to try this out 

    counter += 1

 #for k,v in key_dict.iteritems():
 for v in key_list:
     key_elems = v.split("\t")
     key_chr = key_elems[0]
     key_start = key_elems[1]
     key_end = key_elems[2].strip(' \t\r\n')

for file_name in file_list:
 #  for i in range(1,13)
 #          file_name = "list" + str(i)
            for eachline in file_name:

                    elems = eachline.split("\t")
                    chr = elems[0]
                    start = elems[1]
                    end = elems[2]
        island = elems[3]
        count = elems[4]

        start_diff = abs(int(key_start) - int(start))
                end_diff = abs(int(key_end) - int(end))

        if (chr == key_chr):
                            if(((key_start == start) or (0 <= start_diff <= offset1)) and ((key_end == end) or (0 <= end_diff <= offset2))):
                                    temp_list = out_dict[k]
                                    temp_list[i] = count
                                    out_dict[k] = temp_list
                            else:
                                    continue
                    else:
                            continue


 for key,value in out_dict.iteritems():
     outHandle.write(str(value))

 print("Processing completed!")
```

And here are the files
A1

> ```
> Chromosome01    3187178 3187214 island-16   177976  .   3187178 3187214 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042182 island-32   943 .   5042128 5042182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

A2

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102995 1103064 island-4    1558    .   1102995 1103064 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    3187178 3187227 island-9    81851   .   3187178 3187227 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

A3

> ```
> Chromosome01    4144298 4144467 island-39   354 .   4144298 4144467 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    4144671 4145103 island-41   344 .   4144671 4145103 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

B1

> ```
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042238 island-15   1250    .   5042128 5042238 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042315 5042535 island-16   3256    .   5042315 5042535 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

B3

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102966 1103182 island-2    3910    .   1102966 1103182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042238 island-19   3488    .   5042128 5042238 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

B5

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102966 1103065 island-3    2462    .   1102966 1103065 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042237 island-20   2592    .   5042128 5042237 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

C1

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102973 1103182 island-4    3950    .   1102973 1103182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042237 island-22   4965    .   5042128 5042237 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

C2

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102966 1103182 island-5    3697    .   1102966 1103182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042238 island-29   2730    .   5042128 5042238 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

C4

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102974 1103065 island-6    1673    .   1102974 1103065 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042238 island-28   1857    .   5042128 5042238 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

D1

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102957 1103182 island-5    7654    .   1102957 1103182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    3187180 3187215 island-21   223953  .   3187180 3187215 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

D2

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102973 1103182 island-5    4847    .   1102973 1103182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042237 island-24   2300    .   5042128 5042237 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

D3

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102971 1103182 island-6    7091    .   1102971 1103182 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042238 island-30   2509    .   5042128 5042238 iR  bC  bZ  bS
> ```

The key_list file is:

> ```
> Chromosome01    1102966 1103065 Chromosome01    1102966 1103182
> Chromosome01    1102995 1103064 Chromosome01    3187178 3187214
> Chromosome01    3187178 3187227 Chromosome01    4144298 4144467
> Chromosome01    4144671 4145103 Chromosome01    5042128 5042182
> Chromosome01    5042128 5042238 Chromosome01    5042315 5042535
> Chromosome01    5042495 5042532 Chromosome01    5042663 5043093
> Chromosome01    5042726 5043093 Chromosome01    5043238 5043392
> Chromosome01    5043292 5043394 Chromosome01    5043520 5043752
> Chromosome01    5043523 5043664 Chromosome01    5043547 5043617
> Chromosome01    5043549 5043752 Chromosome01    5043902 5043961
> Chromosome01    5044239 5044547 Chromosome01    5044462 5044505
> Chromosome01    5044679 5044870 Chromosome01    5044679 5045096
> Chromosome01    5044719 5044870 Chromosome01    5044946 5045096
> Chromosome01    5044946 5045115 Chromosome01    5044946 5045168
> Chromosome01    5044993 5045096 Chromosome01    5292510 5292635
> Chromosome01    5292577 5292635 Chromosome01    6698849 6698976
> Chromosome01    13128763    13128846 Chromosome01   13509086    13509169
> Chromosome01    13509086    13509182 Chromosome01   18273293    18273468
> ```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well first off, you’re splitting on “\t” which is a tab. If non of what you’re splitting contains tabs then it’ll only be a single item and element 0 will be the only one that exists. Try splitting on spaces (“ “) instead and see if that helps.

Comment: that's worse than that. he's splitting a char. `"list1"` is not `list1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said in the comments your code can't work because `"list1"` is not `list1`.

the way you open your files is way too convoluted

```
A1_file = sys.argv[1]
with open(A1_file) as A1:
    list1 = A1.readlines()

file_list = ["list1","list2","list3","list4","list5","list6","list7","list8","list9","list10","list11","list12"]

for file_name in file_list:
    for eachline in file_name:
        do_stuff()
```

this, times your 12 files.

```
for i in range(1,13):
    with open(sys.argv[i]) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        do_stuff()
```

here there's no need to create a temporary file_name that doesn't work as expected